# How to avoid INNER JOIN when returning a related entity using a custom constructor in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have something like this:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
  ...
  public User(String login, Division division) {
      this.login = login;
      this.division = division;
  }

  @ManyToOne
  public Division getDivision() {
      return division;
  }
  ...
```

JQPL:

I'm using a custom constructor here because I don't want the query returning the user's password (and others attributes).

```
SELECT new com.xyz.app.beans.User(u.login, u.division)
FROM User u
WHERE u.login = :login
```

SQL generated:

```
select
    user0_.login as col_0_0_,
    user0_.division_id as col_1_0_
from
    dbo.User user0_ 
inner join
    dbo.Division division1_ 
        on user0_.division_id=division1_.id 
where
    user0_.login=?
```

Obviously, if Division is null, my query will return an empty list or throw a NoResultException.
I want the query to return the User regardless if he has a division or not.

There is a way to avoid this?
How to tell to Hibernate to do a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `u.division` in the `select` clause, it implicitly converts to inner join. To include also users without the division, use this

```
SELECT new com.xyz.app.beans.User(u.login, d)
FROM User u left join u.division d
WHERE u.login = :login
```

Comment: Adding _fetch = FetchType.LAZY_ doesn't solved the problem, the generated SQL is the same.
Adding _left join u.division_ added and extra join in the SQL, but it keeps using inner join.
PS.: I realized that is best to don't cascade, so I edited the question.